# SQL - how to write a simple request for a shopping app

Tags: mysql, sql

Actually I've just built the database with that structure :

[image]

So an user can do multiples orders.
each order can have multiples items.

but i can't write a good SQL request to receive a good result.

I need a list of differents orders and on each order i can see: each item with his quantity and the mail of the user who ordered.

I guess the structure is ok but I need the good SQL request.

Thanks!

---

*data example: (i removed useless things)*

`items`:

```
id   name    price
1    Cola    3
2    Pepsi   2
```

`user`:

```
id   email
1    test@admin.com
2    user@test.com
```

`orders`:

```
id   date                   user_id
1    2018-09-24 00:00:00    1
2    2018-09-23 00:00:00    2
```

`order_items` (are the ids usefull ?)

```
id   order_id   items_id   quantity
1    1          1          2
2    1          2          3
3    2          2          8
```

---

*what i would like to have:* (in the front-end). but I know it's impossible to have items listed like that on a SQL result.

`order 1`

```
date                 user                   items
2018-09-24 00:00:00  admin@test.com         Cola x2, Pepsi x3
```

`order 2`

```
date                 user                   items
2018-09-23 00:00:00  user@test.com          Pepsi x8
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images). [mcve]

Comment: Drive from orders.

Comment: @jarlh i edited with an example of data and expected results

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: The expected result can never be a SQL query output. A SQL query result is list of rows where each row has the same columns. You can create a single SQL query to retrieve all information you need, but the presentation logic must be done by something else (source code, reporting application)

Comment: @Conffusion First sorry to not provide an MCRE. I thought the same... 
What single SQL query can i use for this? Do you have something in mind ?
After that i will have to think about how to display this on the application with the front-end

Comment: I've started formatting. Now you can see what we want, and fix the rest of it!

Comment: I've just did, thanks @jarlh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query that will return all information:

```
select o.id "order id", o.date "order date", u.email "email", i.name "item", oi.quantity "quantity"
  from orders
       inner join order_items oi on oi.orders_id = o.id
       inner join user u on u.id = o.user_id
       inner join items i on i.id = oi.items_id
 order by o.id
```

The order by o.id helps in processing the resultset: all items of the same order are together. Can help to write some [control-break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break) logic

Comment: Thanks  @Conffusion ! that is like what i've just found: 

`SELECT orders.id AS orderId, orders.date as orderDate, user.id AS userId, user.email AS userEmail, items.name AS itemName, order_items.quantity, items.price AS itemPrice
FROM orders 
JOIN order_items ON orders.id = order_items.orders_id
JOIN items ON items.id = order_items.items_id
JOIN user ON user.id = orders.user_id
ORDER by orders.id;`

But why inner join? i tried join and inner join and the results are the same

Comment: Don't understand your comment: you've find yourself the same query? So your problem is resolved then ?

Comment: Yes i found the query this morning but i wasn't really sure. So you did confirm that you though kinda the same thing. But i just don't get the INNERs.

Thanks alot

Comment: @Jer `join` does exactly the same thing as `inner join`; there's no difference between the two, `join` is just short-hand.